# Angular - populate demonstration array

Tags: angular

I am developing an application to demonstrate an application and I need to populate an array with 20-30 objects.
Is there a way I could load these from a json file or from a javascript document then load them into a component variable?

Comment: sure there is, just have a look here: https://angular.io/tutorial, or at one of 1000s tutorials on the web

Comment: One reason I don't ask so many questions on stackoverflow is because of the kind of remarks you are making. Always_hungry!

Comment: Don't let the down votes dissuade you from posting. We can try to learn from the comments and do our best to support each other. One thing to remember is that this is not the best place to ask broad or general questions ... it's much more a place to get help when your specific bit of code doesn't work or if you get stuck. :-) Hope to see you here again!

Comment: @jimscafe - I did not downvote you if that's what you are thinking because I was at exactly same point several years ago. I pointed you to official documentation where you can find a great tutorial which would teach you absolutely everything you need to write a solution which you need. Your question looks like you want someone to write and paste a solution for you and this is not a place for it. Besides you asked a general question and you get a general answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others, yes you can read in the data from a JSON file. Here is an example:

```
export class ProductService {
  // Specify the name and location of your json file
  private productUrl = 'api/products/products.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Use Http to read the data from the file
  getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
    // instead of just logging it to the console
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

You can find complete sample code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-Final

Comment: I really enjoyed your course on Angular Router on pluralsight!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

hello you have to create a service and load the json using the http.get method.

Comment: Again, this is correct. Was it just voted down because it does not show code?

Comment: And my entire question was voted down - I am reluctant to ask questions on this forum